# How to calculate difference between one row with multiple rows sql

Tags: sql

I want to calculate the difference between first row with other rows in **sql**. I have a table named 'Trade' like

| date | price |
| --- | --- |
| 2013-01-01 | 70 |
| 2013-01-02 | 71 |
| 2013-01-03 | 72 |
| 2013-02-01 | 73 |
| 2013-02-02 | 74 |
| 2013-02-03 | 75 |

Expected Output:

| date | price | first_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2013-01-01 | 70 | NULL |
| 2013-01-02 | 71 | 1 |
| 2013-01-03 | 72 | 2 |
| 2013-02-01 | 73 | NULL |
| 2013-02-02 | 74 | 1 |
| 2013-02-03 | 75 | 2 |

I used this query:

```
select date,
    price,
    ABS(first_value(price) over (partition by date_trunc('month', date)) - price)
from trades;
```

But I get this output:

| date | price | first_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2013-01-01 | 70 | 0 |
| 2013-01-02 | 71 | 1 |
| 2013-01-03 | 72 | 2 |
| 2013-02-01 | 73 | 0 |
| 2013-02-02 | 74 | 1 |
| 2013-02-03 | 75 | 2 |

Comment: 1 minus 1 equals 0. So everything is correct here. But if you need NULL instead of 0, you can use function IIF. `IIF(ABS(first_value(price) over (partition by date_trunc('month', date)) - price) = 0, NULL, ABS(first_value(price) over (partition by date_trunc('month', date)) - price))`

Comment: Is it first row or first row for that month?

Comment: `date_trunc` is not [tag:sql-server], please correct your tags

Comment: First Row for a month. - @SalmanA

Comment: I want the difference of date wise price in a month. The price difference should be shown in the next date. But in the first row the value should be null because it is the start of month. @demo

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this - check if we have the first value in a month, if so, then `null`:

```
select 
    date, 
    price, 
    case when month = first_value(month) over (partition by date_trunc('month', date))
        then null
        else ABS(first_value(price) over (partition by date_trunc('month', date)) - price) 
from trades;
```